# Instagram API Real-time Photo Update not working

Tags: php, instagram

I am using Instagram's Real-time Photo URL (http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/), I can subscribe successfully because it returns this details:

```
Array
(
    [meta] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [object] => user
            [object_id] => 
            [aspect] => media
            [callback_url] => http://example.com/instagram/
            [type] => subscription
            [id] => 123456
        )

)
```

but when a user uploads a new photo, there's no update being sent on my callback url. Here is my code on my callback URL:

```
mail("myemail@gmail.com","im here","I entered here"); #check if it really does enter here    
if(isset($_GET['hub_challenge']))
{
    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
}
else
{
    #It should enter here if user uploads a new photo
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($data);
    ...some of my codes...brevity...
}
```

I noticed that I am not receiving updates because as you can see on my code, everytime something happens on my callback url it sends me email. So I am not receiving any emails, even if I already checked my spam folder.

Is the instagram real time photo updates API really down? or there's something I need to do?

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

it was necessary to go through the authorization APIinstagram or follow the link specified in the authorization application documentation

> https: //api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

After that, POST requests began to come in callback url